# Parse GeoPoint Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I currently have an iOS App that stores user locations. I'm attempting to query those locations and then display them with Google maps. Right now I'm just trying to query the locations to print them and make sure they're correct before having them embedded in the map, but I keep getting an error where it just shows:

```
[object Object]

[object Object]

[object Object]
```

on page load. I have not worked extensively with JS, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Controller:

```
 var SignoutLocation = Parse.Object.extend('SignoutLocation');

// Display all locaions of signou.
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var query = new Parse.Query(SignoutLocation);
query.limit(10);

query.find().then(function(results) {
  res.render('signoutlocations/index', { signoutlocations: results });
},
function(SignoutLocations) {
  res.send(500, 'Failed loading shit');
});
};
```

EJS Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>THINK Status</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../public/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../public/css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Location List!</h1>
    <% signoutlocations.forEach(function(signoutlocation) { %>
      <h5><%= signoutlocation.get("Location") %></h5>
      <% }) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the results, does each `signoutlocation` have a `get` method or are you just trying to access the "Location" property?  If you're just trying to access the "Location" property, you just need this:
`<%= signoutlocation["Location"] %>`

Comment: I'm just trying to access the Location property. However, when I use that I just get "undefined" instead of "[object Object]"

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the query results that you're getting from the Parse query and make sure that you're seeing a "Locations" property on each of the objects in the results array.